# Do roman numeral symbols have names?

Tags: etymology

Symbols generally seem to have their own names.

For example, *#* is referred to as an 'octothorpe'.

It seems reasonable that roman numerals, like *I*, *V* and *X* should have their own name, that is distinctly different from the numbers they represent, and the characters we use to depict them.

However, I have not been able to find a more suitable name to describe them.

Is there indeed a name for them?

Comment: *one, five, ten* or in Latin *unum , quinque , decem* ... in slang one might say the letters, "eye, vee, ex".. do the "symbols" 1, 5, 10 have "names"

Answer (score 1):

[Unicode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Number_Forms) refer to them simply as "Roman numeral five", etc. I have never heard of any other name for them, other than informal spoken "vee", "ex", "ell", etc.